# AccordionPanel moves Schedule

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have an `accordionPanel` and schedule in my page. But when I expand my `accordionPanel`, my schedule moves down. Why? I use primefaces.

I added a screen: http://zapodaj.net/2a318f4131f84.jpg.html

I am coloring the area in CSS to show that the areas do not overlap each other.

Name of the month and switch between weeks days and months do not move. Only the calendar moves down. Why?

```
<div id="panelMenu">
    <h:form>
        <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="false">
            <p:tab title="#{msg.manage}">
                <p:menu styleClass="selection">
                    <p:menuitem action="#{userMB.patientList()}" value="Pacjenci" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
                    <p:menuitem action="#{userMB.doctorList()}" value="Lekarze" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
                    <p:menuitem action="#{userMB.inactiveAccountList()}" value="Nieaktywne" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
                </p:menu>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="#{msg.myAccount}">
                <p:menu styleClass="selection">
                    <p:menuitem value="#{msg.edit}" action="#{userMB.editMyAccount()}" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="#{msg.logout}" action="#{loginMB.logout()}" icon="ui-icon-power"/>
                </p:menu>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </h:form>
</div>

    <div id="visitsRegisterSecretary">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:growl id="messages"/>  
            <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{visitSecretaryMB.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" locale="pl" timeZone="GMT+2" >  
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{visitSecretaryMB.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />  
                <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{visitSecretaryMB.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />  
                <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{visitSecretaryMB.onEventMove}" update="messages" />  
                <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{visitSecretaryMB.onEventResize}" update="messages" />  
            </p:schedule>
```

CSS: panelMenu to accordionPanel

```
#panelMenu {
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
}
```

visits to schedule

```
#visits {
    padding-top: 200px;
    width: 700px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

both in:

```
 #all {
    width: 901px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code Orange.

Comment: I edited first post. Please look it.

Comment: Your xhtml is not compiling. Can you please update it because it's incomplete. `Cannot find component with identifier "eventDetails" referenced from "form:schedule".`

Comment: I made a few assumption with my answer, but I think I know what you were trying to say after playing around with the code. In the future, please be careful with what you post. There is no id for the rules `#visits` and `#all` and your xhtml does not compile. Let me know if this works, if not update your code so that it includes all the relevant information and I'll take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floated elements remain part of the normal flow of a web page. Therefore, when you expand
 `panelMenu` and the height overlaps with `<p:schedule>`'s parent box, it will affect the position of `<p:schedule>` and it will cause it to move. The overlap does happen even though you're not seeing it. So, one thing you can do to prevent that is to take `panelMenu` out of the normal flow of the page by using `absolute` positioning (within a `relative` positioned box).

**Note**: There is no `id` with the value `visits` on the xhtml provided. Therefore, I'm going to assume that the rule given was actually for `div id="visitsRegisterSecretary"` and I have changed `#visits` to `#visitsRegisterSecretary` in the CSS.

All you have to do is wrap your `accordionPanel` within the two divs below

```
<div id="panelMenuContainer">
    <div id="panelMenu">
        <h:form>
             <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="false">
                 <p:tab title="#{msg.manage}">
             <!--Remainder ommitted -->
             </p:accordionPanel>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then define the following rules in your stylesheet

```
#panelMenuContainer {
    position:relative; 
}

#panelMenu {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 880px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

The `left` property will cause `panelMenu` to move accordingly.

**Additional Notes**:

1. I'm just guessing the value of `left` in `#panelMenu` so change as
   needed.
2. Also, you can remove the `padding-top` rule in
       `#visitsRegisterSecretary` if you want both `<h:forms>` to align
       correctly (assuming that's what you're after).

You can refer to these links for a more in-depth explanation

[All about floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

[Absolute positioning inside relative positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)